What does A-coefficient, A-star-coefficient, Leontief inverse, and Ghosh inverse means in EEIO?
All 4 features are dependent of the transaction Z table, where Z table is an NxN matrix of sectors representing input/output or export/import.
Intuitively, I'm still confused by what they do.
From https://pymrio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/terminology.html documentation:
Z: transactions matrix, inter industry flows
A: inter-industry coefficients (direct requirements matrix)
L: Leontief inverse. leontief inverse (total requirements matrix) (multi regional approach)
More context for my understanding:
A_coefficient
How much of the output from a sector (e.g., me as a landlord) is required by another sector or customer as an input.
Example: If Im a landlord, the A_coefficient describes how much of tenant A’s total consumption (in terms of their needs or expenses) is dependent on the housing I provide. For instance, if this coefficient is 10%, it indicates that tenant A allocates 10% of their total expenditure to renting space from me.
As_coefficient
How much each sector contributes to the output of another sector, showing how the outputs of one sector are used as inputs by others.
Again in the landlord scenario, As_coefficient tells me my total rental income is derived from tenant A. So if tenant A contributes 20% to my total rental income, that would be reflected in the As_coefficient.
Is my understanding right or was it the other way round
